# LXC container troubleshooting

Tags: troubleshooting, lxc

I'm trying to start my container **node01**. 
It was working before and I just can't understand why all my containers (3) stopped working in one time after reboot. Actually they not starting. After **lxc-start -n node01** it just hangs and console don't show startup process. Pressing the keys just reflect symbols but nothing happening.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric 3.0.0-14-server x86_64 lxc-start

In /var/log/syslog next lines shows after

```
Jan 24 11:19:14 us1 kernel: [11733.905542] device veth1xlPzk entered promiscuous mode
Jan 24 11:19:14 us1 kernel: [11733.905970] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth1xlPzk: link is not ready
Jan 24 11:19:14 us1 kernel: [11734.053982] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth1xlPzk: link becomes ready
Jan 24 11:19:14 us1 kernel: [11734.054016] br0: port 2(veth1xlPzk) entering forwarding state
Jan 24 11:19:14 us1 kernel: [11734.054019] br0: port 2(veth1xlPzk) entering forwarding state
```

Ping to container is working, but I can't ssh to it.

Only after **lxc-stop -n node01** from another terminal my first terminal stops hangs.

in /var/log/syslog shows next lines:

```
Jan 24 11:19:25 us1 kernel: [11744.448111] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Jan 24 11:19:25 us1 kernel: [11744.496065] veth1xlPzk: no IPv6 routers present
Jan 24 11:20:15 us1 kernel: [11794.424915] br0: port 2(veth1xlPzk) entering forwarding state
Jan 24 11:20:15 us1 kernel: [11794.426315] br0: port 2(veth1xlPzk) entering disabled state
```

How to force it working?

Comment: I see nothing here that would indicate a problem. Can you open a console to your containers?

Comment: I was not able to. But it is too late to seek problems, I just destroyed those containers. Somehow the problems was with all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question was provided in the comments.

The solution was to back up the data, destroy the LXC containers,and start fresh.

> I just destroyed those containers. Somehow the problems was with all of them.